# How to handle http post request, issued from android?

Tags: php, android, http-post

I'm developing an `Android` app that sends data through `http post` (the data is string value).

I have done up to the Android part, but I'm totally new to PHP. Here is I want to be done:

The PHP page gets the string data, and generates a response according to the value (i.e. if the value is 12345, it says you have sent 12345), and that response is sent back to android...

Can anyone help me here please.

Comment: Share some code which you've tried yet! We will have a look, and then can try to help.

Comment: Here is the code I tried.


<?php
    # Read GET variables
    $fName = $_POST['data'];
    
 
    # Create output string
    $str = "\$data\";
 
    # Open and write to file
    $fh = fopen("a.txt");
    fwrite($fh, $str);
    fclose($fh);
 
    echo "done";
?>

Comment: To allow the mobile application communicate with your web application you need to create a web service. REST API http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-beginners-introduction-to-http-and-rest/ or SOAP API
http://www.vankouteren.eu/blog/2009/03/simple-php-soap-example/ or simple php cURL
http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A POST request issued from Android is no different from any other post request from any other place (Web page, desktop application etc).

You will handle it in exactly the same way as a request from any other source.

You can simply use `print_r($_POST)` to print out all the POST request data.

Comment: That's true the POST request is same, but I need help in handling that request. Coz I don't know how to program in PHP.

Comment: I tried print_r($_POST), I'm pressing the post button in my app but nothing is happening on the php page. Where exactly it prints? Sorry for so basic questions.